# Amazon DynamoDB: How to search for range of dates?

Tags: date, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB and some items there have a date field. The date field is a string of the format {YYYY-MM-DD}. What should I have to write that the DB will retrieve all items which date field is between a start date and an end date?

This is my code:

```
function searchFile(from_date, until_date) {
    AWS.config = new AWS.Config({accessKeyId: '***', secretAccessKey: '***', region: '***'});
    var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});
    var params = {
        "TableName" : '***',
        FilterExpression: "Date_ = :date",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
          // What should I write here?
        },
    }
    dynamodb.scan(params, function(err,data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(data);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The DynamoDB stores dates as String. You can use `BETWEEN` operator to get the range of dates.

**createdate** - is the attribute name

```
FilterExpression: "createdate BETWEEN :date1 and :date2",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
         ":date1": "2010-05-05",
         ":date2": "2011-10-04",
    }
```

> Date  S (string type). The Date values are stored as ISO-8601 formatted
>   strings.
>
> BETWEEN : Greater than or equal to the first value, and less than or
>   equal to the second value.